# Let a Stored procedure return IQueryable<T> not ObjectResult<TElement>

Tags: linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I would like to be able to use this kind of query with a stored procedure as I do it using a simple `DbSet<Balance>`

```
var bals = db.Balances
              .Where(b => db.Balances.Any(b2 => b.Number.StartsWith(b2.Number)&&b2.Number!=b.Number))
              .ToList();
```

This works but when I try it with an imported function from a stored procedure:

```
var bals = db.GetCustomBalances("2015")
             .Where(b => db.Balances
                           .Any(b2 => b.Number.StartsWith(b2.Number)&&b2.Number!=b.Number))
             .ToList();
```

this doesn't work:

> cannot enumerate enumerable more than once

How to solve this ?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the problem is because the stored procedure call `db.GetCustomBalances("2015")` returns a `ObjectResult<TElement>` instead of `IQueryable<TElement>` as with `DbSet<TableName>`

How to let a stored procedure return `IQueryable<T>` and not a `ObjectResult<TElement>`?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you actually trying to achieve. Since in current form Where condition is useless since there always will be at least one balance which Number starts with Number of current balance (it is current balance himself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do that, you could use a trick: open a transaction, create a temporary table (a # table in sql server) execute the procedure by inserting the result directly into that temp table ( do that using ExecuteStoreCommand api but i would prefeer to abstract and isolate this using an interface so that if you change your SGBD you will be able to change this sql statement also) and what remains to do is to map somehow the temporary table to a context entity to be able to make joins with your sp resultset. I've done this some time ago by using another trick: create a bogus table that has the same schema as stored procedure result, map it in Entity framework and use that table for joins. But you will have to hook the sql that is executed to replace table name with temporary table name. You can do that by implementing the IDbCommandInterceptor and manipulate the DbCommand commandText before it is sent to your database server. More details about it you will find here: http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/2394/Entity-Framework-60-Intercepting-SQL-produced-by-EF.aspx Keep in mind that this solution is not necesary sql server dependent because almost any SGBD has temp tables and you can create an abstract factory that serve an IDbCommandInterceptor for each SGBD provider. Another thing to keep in mind: remember to delete temp table if you reuse the same connection, otherwise you don't have to bother because every time a sql connection goes back to the pool, a connection cleanup mechanism is called for that connection. For example, in sql server the sp_resetconnection is called